# C# string from one function to another

Tags: c#

in a c# program that i made, i read some values from an INI file,put them in string, in function UPLOAD and i make a database manager for those values to connect the user to a db. Now, i need to read those strings from another function, you see it below. What shall i do ?

```
        public Upload()
    {
        #region INI PROPERTIES and Variables

        INIFile inif = new INIFile(@".\Settings\AppSettings.ini");
        //Values for DatabaseManager dbm
        //Hosting Server IP
        string srv_ip = inif.Read("DatabaseSettings", "IP_adress");
        //Database Username
        string srv_uname = inif.Read("DatabaseSettings", "Admin_Username");
        //Database Password
        string srv_pass = inif.Read("DatabaseSettings", "Admin_Password");
        //Database Name
        string srv_dbname = inif.Read("DatabaseSettings", "Database_Name");

        //Values for DatabaseManager dbm

        //Fingerprint of Hosting Server IP
        string ftp_fingerprint = inif.Read("ProgramSettings", "fingerprint");
        //Host
        string ftp_host = inif.Read("ProgramSettings", "host");
        //Username
        string ftp_username = inif.Read("ProgramSettings", "username");
        //Password
        string ftp_pass = inif.Read("ProgramSettings", "password");

        #endregion
        InitializeComponent();
        DatabaseManager dbm = new DatabaseManager(srv_ip, srv_uname, srv_pass, srv_dbname);
        dbm.Init();
    }
```

And the other function. I need from the first to store the variables into the strings that you can see on the second.

```
    private void upload_btn_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {

            string fingerprint = ftp_fingerprint;
            string host = ftp_host;
            string username = ftp_username;
            string password = ftp_pass;

            FtpManager ftpm = new FtpManager(host, username, password, fingerprint, ProgressCallback);

            string remoteFolder = "/var/whatever"; // Name of directory to upload
            string remoteName;    // Name of file to save on server

    //some more code
          }
```

Problem solved by making those variables fields. Thank you all for your answers i appreciate each one of you for your time.

Comment: You may make the variables class members. So you can access them from every function in the class.

Comment: You have to put all the code in one function. That's all you can do. Just one big function. This is called the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: Ed may be right - Could you show us all of your code?

Comment: @Enigmativity You want to see my function? It's really, really big.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - No, I want to see Neo's.

Comment: @EdPlunkett you may want to consider prefixing ( like "trolling:") your comments if you are trolling... (if not - sorry for misunderstanding, you are definitely welcome to express your opinions even if it is against common recommendations of writing good code).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to go is to make them fields.

```
private string ftp_fingerprint;
private string ftp_host;
private string ftp_username;
private string ftp_pass;

public Upload()
{
    #region INI PROPERTIES and Variables

    INIFile inif = new INIFile(@".\Settings\AppSettings.ini");
    //Values for DatabaseManager dbm
    //Hosting Server IP
    string srv_ip = inif.Read("DatabaseSettings", "IP_adress");
    //Database Username
    string srv_uname = inif.Read("DatabaseSettings", "Admin_Username");
    //Database Password
    string srv_pass = inif.Read("DatabaseSettings", "Admin_Password");
    //Database Name
    string srv_dbname = inif.Read("DatabaseSettings", "Database_Name");

    //Values for DatabaseManager dbm

    //Fingerprint of Hosting Server IP
    ftp_fingerprint = inif.Read("ProgramSettings", "fingerprint");
    //Host
    ftp_host = inif.Read("ProgramSettings", "host");
    //Username
    ftp_username = inif.Read("ProgramSettings", "username");
    //Password
    ftp_pass = inif.Read("ProgramSettings", "password");

    #endregion
    InitializeComponent();
    DatabaseManager dbm = new DatabaseManager(srv_ip, srv_uname, srv_pass, srv_dbname);
    dbm.Init();
}

private void upload_btn_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

    string fingerprint = ftp_fingerprint;
    string host = ftp_host;
    string username = ftp_username;
    string password = ftp_pass;

    FtpManager ftpm = new FtpManager(host, username, password, fingerprint, ProgressCallback);

    string remoteFolder = "/var/whatever"; // Name of directory to upload
    string remoteName;    // Name of file to save on server

    //some more code
}
```

Comment: Yes making them fields fixed the issue in seconds. But is it a good technique?

Comment: @NeoEssence not necessarily

Comment: @NeoEssence you're probably better off future proofing yourself by passing in a class of a particular interface with all the properties that you need, that way the upload function can be a bit more dynamic and doesn't rely on a ini file

Comment: @NeoEssence - Given where you're at in C# I think this is probably the best answer for them right now. Longer-term there are of course better ways.

Comment: @NeoEssence - Ideally I'd like to see the rest of your code to suggest a better option.